# unable to center align single div of absolute positioned thead tr th div

Tags: html, css

I have a table with three fields `Sno` `Date` and `Amount`. I need `Sno` and `Date` to be left aligned , `Amount` only to be right aligned.

Using html table with css

css use

```
thead tr th div,
tfoot tr td div {
  position: absolute;
  //color: #fff;
  //padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  line-height: normal;
  // left:0;
  // right:0;
  z-index: 2;
  //  text-align: center  !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}
```

due to having `position: absolute;` unable to set `text-align: right !important;`

Complete css file and html:

```css
page-dsh-trd-det {
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #efefef;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
  .container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 85vh;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top: 41px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 41px solid transparent;
    margin-left: 0px!important;
  }
  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  td+td {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  td,
  th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #efefef;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  thead tr th,
  tfoot tr td {
    height: 0;
    //line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    // color: transparent;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  thead tr th div,
  tfoot tr td div {
    position: absolute;
    //color: #fff;
    //padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    line-height: normal;
    // left:0;
    // right:0;
    z-index: 2;
    //  text-align: center  !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
  }
  thead tr th div {
    //border-left: 1px solid #000;
    // text-align: right  !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }
  tfoot tr td div {
    //border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
  }
  thead tr th div {
    top: 0;
  }
  tfoot tr td div {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  thead tr th:first-child div,
  tfoot tr td:first-child div {
    border-left: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div width='100%'>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width:5%">
                  <div [style.background-color]="this.user.headercolor">Sno</div>
                </th>
                <th style="width:10%">
                  <div [style.background-color]="this.user.headercolor">Date</div>
                </th>
                <th style="width:15%">
                  <div [style.background-color]="this.user.headercolor">Amount</div>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a specific css style to achieve that. You can have `.text-right {text-align: right !important;}` then you call it in the HTML. Like this:

```css
.text-left {
  text-align: left !important
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right !important
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-left" style="width:5%">
      <div [style.background-color]="this.user.headercolor">Sno</div>
    </th>
    <th class="text-left" style="width:10%">
      <div [style.background-color]="this.user.headercolor">Date</div>
    </th>
    <th class="text-right" style="width:15%">
      <div [style.background-color]="this.user.headercolor">Amount</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Created and added class text-right but it let Label Amount to be disappeared from the screen